# How can I include a remote library as raw source code into my project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

If there is a code library in a single file, is it possible for Visual Studio to "include" it remotely?

Consider a library I wrote -- [Nemmet](https://github.com/deanebarker/nemmet).  Basically, the entire thing exists in a single file, by design.  It's a very limited library, with barely any dependencies.

For people to include the source (even myself, in other projects), they would have to do one of the following:

1. Download the repo and add the project to their solution
2. Create the file, and copy and paste `Nemmet.cs` into it

Yes, they could install a Nuget package, but then you get the compiled DLL in your project, not the source. Nuget is really about *functionality*, not *source code*. Additionally, it requires me as the library owner to create and maintain the package, which I'm really not that interested in doing.

What I'm looking for is a more "casual" way of including raw source code into a project.

What would be nice is if Visual Studio could do a "remote include" or something. I'd love to be able to bind a source file to a URL (the "raw" URL at Github) and have VS update the contents of the file every once in a while, or on-demand (right click > "Update from URL").

(Yes, this assumes you trust the source. Let's assume you do. You'd have the same issue with any included library.)

Is there anything like this available in some way?  Should I just WGet it?  Am I not thinking of a more obvious way to achieve the same end?

Comment: Why not just include the .cs file in the nuget package instead of the dll?

Comment: The problem is more than I don't want to have to create and maintain the Nuget packages for my own libraries, or depend on packages being available for other libraries.  If the source is on GitHub, I'd rather just use it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) which is a dependency manager for .NET projects.  Many of us in the F# community use it quite a lot but there is no reason it isn't equally applicable to the rest of the .NET world.

Basically, you create a `paket.dependencies` file for your project to list your dependenies.  It supports:

- Nuget dependencies:

  `nuget EntityFramework`
- git repositories

  `git https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket.git`
- Single files

  `http http://www.fssnip.net/raw/1M/test1.fs`
- Github dependencies

  `github forki/FsUnit FsUnit.fs`

Here is the [getting started guide](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the same thing, but I found a way to "Add as Link" in a Visual Studio project.  You can add a source code file without *actually adding it* to your project.

When adding an "existing item," dropped the "Add" button down to "Add as Link."  It will add a placeholder to the file to your project, and compile it in, but *leave the file where it is*. This means you could have a central project on your file system, and use that code in all sorts of projects without having multiple copies of the file sitting around.  Changing the file in your central project would change it in all the other projects.

Again, not the same thing, but still helpful.